# Joomla! <?anything instead of <?php?

Tags: php, joomla, url-rewriting

How Joomla! is made so as to when I create a template I can write **`<?anything`** instead of **`<?php`** in template files?

In a simple PHP file I can't do that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a programming language other than php and javascript?

Comment: @Elin NO! I only want to know how Joomla! made so as to when I create a template which has ".php" files inside, I can write <?anything instead of <?php. If I write <?anything the PHP functions are called, so it uses PHP.

Comment: Oh Joomla doesn't do that. That just means you have PHP short tags enabled.  But it's really not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to change `<?php` to `<?anything` as it's rather pointless. The only short way is to use `<?=` which automatically echo's something. For example:

```
<?= 'hello world'; ?>
```

which will simply output:

```
hello world
```

That said, you must enable short tags in your server settings to be able to do this.

Please also be careful with adding custom PHP files to your template. Always ensure that **if** you do this, that you stick to Joomla coding standards.